# How to get CVS notification emails to contain link to diff?

Tags: cvs

Is there any way to get CVS e-mail notifications to inlude links to my ViewCVS server where clicking a link could bring up the diff ?

Currently my loginfo file just has entries like this 
^installation       cat | /usr/bin/Mail -s "[cvs-update installation]" devteam@company.com

The e-mails we all then get (Afairly standard I imagine) contain the commit message and list of files changed.

Cheers,
Ro

Answer (score 2):

http://www.badgers-in-foil.co.uk/projects/cvsspam/

Seems to be the way to do this

Answer (score 1):

Or ActivityMail

http://search.cpan.org/~dwheeler/activitymail-1.26/bin/activitymail

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible with ViewCVS, but I know it's possible with WebSVN, though that would require you to convert from CVS to SVN.

Here's an [link text](http://thefireflyproject.us/diff.php?repname=firefly-api&path=%2Flibstructfire%2Fsip%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fsip.cpp&rev=0&sc=0) from my WebSVN of a diff. It's probably also possible for you to write an extension to ViewCVS yourself if ViewCVS doesn't have a way to do it, using [enscript highlighting](http://www.markkurossi.com/genscript/)

EDTI: This is supported in ViewCVS, and it seems that you could probably do this by extending your post-commit hook script (I'm assuming that's how you doing notification emails).

The format seems to be:

```
http://yoursite/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/path/to/change/name_of_changed_file?view=diff&r1=insert_head_num_here&r2=insert_head_num_minus_one_here&diff_format=h
```

For example, from gentoo's viewcvs repository.

```
http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/path-sandbox/trunk/COPYING?view=diff&r1=363&r2=8&diff_format=h
```

Since the URL to the diff has a given format, you should be able to process the information from each commit into a series of links, each link pointing to a diff for a changed file.

Hope that's helpful